Search in Archived table Automatically or not in sql server?
I partitioned my main table in sql server which has over 12,000,000 records and archived the records before a certain date. My question is, without changing the queries that were written before partitioning this table, if the desired record is not in the partitioned table, will it be automatically searched for that  in the archive table or not?
For Example: my Partitioned table is Ordering.Parcel by CreationDateTime datetime(7) partitioned column. I Archived this table and moved records before date '20-03-2024'  to Ordering.Parcel_Archived. Now the following query is automatically searched in table Ordering.Parcel_Archived if no record is returned in table Ordering.Parcel or not?
   Select Id, First_name from Ordering.Parcel where   
   CreationDateTime < '20-03-2024'

it is very difficult to change or add to my written queries in my program.

So you have two tables, and you want to keep querying only the table name Ordering.Parcel?
No, it isn't possible to search two tables without either changing the query or the schema.
One option is to create a view named Ordering.Parcel and have that view do two SELECT that you combine with a UNION ALL. That requires you to rename the Ordering.Parcel table to something else.
Another option is to change your query instead, so your query does a UNION ALL.
Regardless, if you go by any of above options consider maintaiing a check constraint on each table specifying the allowed range of dates. This way, it is possible that the optimizer can skip the table that impossibly can contain any rows based on your WHERE clause.
Yet another option is of course to have two queries. Check number of rows returned from the first table and then conditionally run a second query against the second table.
